# Bash syntax error: syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: bash, syntax-error

Hello I'm trying to do a bash script for send a mail if 10 or more lines are written in a file, but get this output error: syntax error near unexpected token `else'

this is the script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=file.txt
lines=$(wc -l file | awk '{print $1}')
email="my@email.com"

if (( lines > 10 ))
then
 (mailx -s "There are more than 10 lines in file" ${email}
 else 
  echo -n file
 fi
done
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `${lines}` line after the else? All this will do is try to execute a number which will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closing paren after the `mailx` line. Actually you should be able to delete that paren, I don't see a need for it.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned by another user, you should be able to remove the  ( before mailx or else add ) to the end of that line and to add to this, it may be worthwhile using a tool that has syntax highlighting when writing scripts as it makes troubleshooting things like this a lot easier. I use a full IDE such as  Pycharm or Visual Studio Code with bash plugin installed. Or you could use any text editor with bash syntax highlighting.